# What are the problems with my jquery post?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a website with a google maps API. I have made it so that the user can right click on the map and place a marker, and then the console prints the coordinates (coords) in the console because of the line that reads

```
console.log(coords)
```

I am now trying to get these coords, which I can see in the console every time I place a marker, into a database. I have downloaded and called on jquery in a script tag in the header of the html page, but my post request is not working at all.

I am sure there are several problems with mine. I was basing my request off the example one:

```
$.post(url,[data],[callback],[type]);
```

mine is:

```
$.post(map.html,[coords],[return render_template("apology.html")],[.append]);
```

I wasn't sure what the type or the callback function should be.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: the `[]` in those docs just mean the parameter is optional

Comment: *"I wasn't sure what the type or the callback function should be."* It's in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/): *"dataType Type: String The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html)."* For `callback`: *"success Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )"*
"* That means it's a function that gets passed three arguments. A function is defined either using the `function` keyword (e.g. `function foo() {}`) or using the arrow function syntax (`() => {}`).

Comment: See MDN for general introductory information about JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example from jquery documentation.

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "some data" }, function( data ) {
  console.log( data.name );
  console.log( data.time );
}, "json");
```

Change your code to something like below. Just remove `[]`.

```
$.post(map.html, coords, function() {
  return render_template("apology.html")
}, 'json');
```

Make sure `map.html` is actually the url you want to send your post request.

For the last parameter, if you are sure that your server accepts `json` then the type of data you are sending should be `json` too. Otherwise look for other possible types such as `xml, script, text, html`

Comment: first parameter is the url that post request is going to be sent to. It seems that `map.html` is not the url. You should correct it with the actual path.